How to find the double integral of an absolute value trig function?
I have this double integral:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |\sin(y-x)|dydx$$
And I'm struggling to solve it.
I have reached the answer $4/\pi^2$ however my answer isn't what the textbook says is correct, which is $2\pi$.
Since it's an absolute value I tried this for the new bounds:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0 \int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin(y-x))dydx - \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{-\pi/2}^0 (\sin(y-x))dydx$$
I'm not really sure what to do, I'm pretty sure my new bounds are wrong but I'm not sure. Any kind of help would be appreciated!!

Draw the original region of integration then draw the region of integration of your attempt to split the integral. Do you see the discrepancy between the shapes?

Since $y-x\in[-\pi,\pi]$, $\sin(y-x)\ge0\iff y\ge x$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^x-\sin(y-x)dy+\int_x^{\pi/2}\sin(y-x)dy\right)dx\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\left[\cos(y-x)\right]_{-\pi/2}^x+\left[-\cos(y-x)\right]_x^{\pi/2}\right)dx\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(2-\cos(-\pi/2-x)-\cos(\pi/2-x)\right)dx\\&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}2dx\\
&=2\pi.
\end{align}$$
This is confirmed by Wolfram Alpha.
Edit: most of the calculations above can be avoided by noticing that for any fixed $x$, the map $y\mapsto|\sin(y-x)|$ has period $\pi$ hence its integral over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is the same as over $[x,x+\pi]$, namely $\int_0^\pi\sin t\,dt=2$.
